# Text file incorrect tell() positions

Tags: python, file, text, tell

Trying to index text file (formatted as one sentence per line) ... but the character positions seem to get skewed at some point ... in the example below this happen at line/sentence 19.

First I check to find the positions and then I read the same range, but the calculated range(279) is 4 characters bigger !

Any idea what could be the reason ?

---

```
    start = fh.tell()
    line = fh.readline()
    end = fh.tell()
    print(f"line:{i},pos:{start}-{end} : {end-start}\n{line}")

    line:19,pos:2703-2982 : 279
    Many revolutionaries of the 19th century such as William Godwin ( 1756 – 1836 ) and Wilhelm Weitling ( 1808 – 1871 ) would contribute to the anarchist doctrines of the next generation but did not use " anarchist " or " anarchism " in describing themselves or their beliefs .
```

---

```
    fh.seek(2703)
    print(fh.read(279))


    Many revolutionaries of the 19th century such as William Godwin ( 1756 – 1836 ) and Wilhelm Weitling ( 1808 – 1871 ) would contribute to the anarchist doctrines of the next generation but did not use " anarchist " or " anarchism " in describing themselves or their beliefs .
    The
```

---

[image: hex view]

Comment: Are you on Windows? Newlines are 2 bytes CR+LF on Windows.

Comment: Are you trying to count byte length, codepoint length, or grapheme length?

Comment: linux.. and when i look in hex dont see anything unusual..

Comment: Well, what you pasted uses a `U+2013 EN DASH`, which is a single codepoint but 3 bytes `E2 80 93`

Comment: hmm.. do i have to open the file with some encoding

Comment: @sten: Seems like it automatically got opened with the correct encoding (the en dash would not appear correctly if the encoding used was incorrect). If you wanted the raw bytes without decoding (so `read`ing 10 of them made `tell` report an offset of 10) you'd open in binary mode.

Comment: @o11c can i do something when converting the original file to one-sentence per line to fix those dashes and similar chars.. i use nltk to capture sentences.... OR even do something with this file !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tell` on text-oriented files has no documented meaning. It's officially an opaque cookie that can be used with `seek`, and otherwise cannot be counted on to have any meaning. This provides flexibility to encode additional information required by the encoding in use into the cookie, and even when it represents a number of bytes into a one-byte-per-character encoding file, it can differ from the number of characters read because of line-ending translations. Similarly, in encodings with variable length character encodings, a byte position would not correspond to character counts. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell):

> #### `tell()`
>
> Return the current stream position as an opaque number. The number does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage.

In short, you cannot and should not rely on the number produced to have any meaning that is useful to you *aside* from passing it back into a `seek` call. The value is an implementation detail.

---

sten: this seems like working.. will test more to be sure, thanks this is life saver.. will approve the answer in a jiff ;)

> The simpler way would be to do file.seek(ix[pos]) then do file.readline()

Comment: do u know of a way to index a file so i can jump around by line-number

Comment: @sten: Typically I'd recommend just using [the `linecache` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html) rather than trying to implement such a cache yourself. It handles all the grunt work for you. The alternative is just to make a `dict` mapping line numbers to the result of `tell` after each line was read (so if you want to seek back to a given line, you just look up the line number to find the associated cookie). If you can't use the module, I'd still recommend reimplementing it with minor tweaks (it's designed for working with source files with encoding declarations).

Comment: thats what i'm doing storing all line pos I read ... then doing ... read( ix[pos+1] - ix[pos] ) ... linecache prob.. wont work cause I do multiple files ~130MB each ... the .hdf5 pos-index is ~30MB so far

Comment: is this the wrong way to read( ix[pos+1] - ix[pos] )

Comment: @sten: The simpler way would be to do `file.seek(ix[pos])` then do `file.readline()`. If you want to do reading at raw byte offsets for a fixed number of bytes (so it's not scanning for newlines, you have to revert to binary mode (manually decoding after if you like), because that's the only documented way that subtracting two `tell` results has any useful/portable meaning.

Comment: hmmm.. this may work .... seek, readline instead of read ..thanks will try