# file.tell() after a write is not correct in append mode?

Tags: python, file, io, posix, seek

The method `tell()` returns a lower value than expected. It does not point to the position of the last written byte.

Consider this example:

```py
# appender.py
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1], 'a+b')
file.seek(0)
file.write(b'56789')
print('offset: ', file.tell())
```

```bash
$ printf "01234" > myfile
$ python appender.py myfile
offset:  5
```

The value should be 10 instead of 5.

This is an equivalence in C:

```c
/* appender.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if (argc!=2){
    puts("usage ./test file");
    return 1;
  }
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  write(fd, "01234", 5);
  printf("offset: %ld\n", lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR));
  return 0;
}
```

which returns the expected value:

```bash
$ printf "01234" > myfile
$ ./appender
offset: 10
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be a bug report to Python.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell) says: `tell()`: Return the current stream position as an opaque number. The number does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage.

Comment: I suspect this is because you opened the file in append mode. Seeking 0 as the file start is not consistent with the choice to append.

Comment: @VBB watch out, that `.tell()` note is specific to the `io.TextIOBase`, while this is (probably) a `io.BufferedRandom`

Comment: @user207421 I disagree, it's unlikely to be a bug, much more likely to be a misunderstanding of how `seek()` and `tell()` work for a file opened in append mode.

Comment: Hum, I'm wavering on that comment now. The [manual for seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) says that `os.SEEK_SET or 0 – start of the stream (the default); offset should be zero or positive` is the default, so the behaviour is not as expected. But the [manual for open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) says `and 'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems, means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position)`: is OP's example falling in the case where the write ignores the seek position?

Comment: I can reproduce OP's observation with Python 3.11 on Windows run from either Git Bash or cmd, however, so it's clearly not just on Unix.

Comment: Answer is there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73495319/text-file-incorrect-tell-positions

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I created an issue in CPython: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/116376

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of this old one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010322/python-3-tell-gets-out-of-sync-with-file-pointer-in-appendread-mode

Answer (score 0):

From my experimentation, `file.write()` appends at the end of the file regardless of the seek position of the file.

If I augment your example like this:

```
# appender.py
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1], 'a+b')
file.seek(0)
file.write(b'56789')
file.seek(0)
file.write(b'98765')
print('offset: ', file.tell())
```

and run your test:

```
$ printf "01234" > myfile
$ python appender.py myfile
offset:  5
$ cat myfile
012345678998765
```

Notice how both calls to `file.seek(0)` were effectively ignored.

Looking at the [manual for open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), it says this about *mode*:

> and 'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems, means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position)

This appear to apply not just to Unix systems, but some others as well. I tested this with Python 3.11 on Windows in both cmd and Git Bash and got the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes, calls `file.seek` should be ignored before a write. The problem is the value returned by `file.tell()`